# Why does my layout auto scroll without a scroll view?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have been having some trouble implementing a toolbar but it never stays in one place. This is due to some auto scroll thing with `recyclerView` in the layout, which I weird since there is no `scrollView`.

How do I fix this so the tool bar is in a fixed position when I scroll?

[image]

Here is my code so you can tell me what I need to do in order to fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context="com.example.user.app.Utils.ViewProfileFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorS50Alpha"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_signinandregister"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorProfileBack" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_profile_01"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout5">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfilephoto"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.361" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Foster The People"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfilephoto"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="I like bacon and cheese sandwiches"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfileBackphoto"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAddFriend"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ivProfilephoto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.418"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/addfriend02" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivRemoveFriend"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ivProfilephoto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.418"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/removefriend02" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tbProfiletabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar01"
    android:layout_marginTop="264dp"
    android:background="@color/colorS50Alpha"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorSearch">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Center" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lvProfilePosts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tbProfiletabs"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/profileTabsViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tbProfiletabs">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please describe what exactly happens with toolbar when you scroll

Comment: post relevant screenshots so that the problem is clear

Comment: I just added a screenshot.

Comment: @DickHarris  Can you show Activity layout, where you want to put this Fragment

Comment: That is the Activity layout.

Comment: try the answer with code given below

Comment: Code is working fine, only `RecyclerView` is scrolling, so what's the problem?

Comment: like this: https://imgur.com/a/X2axf

Comment: Kind of but i want everything except the the toolbar to move when scrolling.

Comment: This layout works perfectly on my emulator, without moving Toolbar on scrolling :)

Comment: That's weird, it should work with mine as well. What is the code in your style script in your values folder?

Comment: nothing, just empty test project

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing recycler code like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/lvProfilePosts"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar01"
android:visibility="visible" />
```

I think toolbar is staying up there but recycle view is scrolling over the toolbar.

Comment: What is the box in the beginning? What view is that?

Comment: What do you mean? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

add above lines to your root layout, Relative layout in your case

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/actBackgroundColor"
tools:context="com.playglam.activities.ViewAddressActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <com.playglam.others.custom_view.MyTextViewThin
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_20"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvAddress"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabNewAddress"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_10"
    app:elevation="@dimen/dim_5"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding another layout below my toolbar?

Comment: Forget about layout below property, you are using Linear Layout it will manage

Comment: It ain't working. if even you have some basic code with a toolbar and recyclerView, that would also help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a `NestedScrollView`.