# How to render a single Fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm curious i have only used `fragments` with tabs, but is there a way where i can just render **one** fragment in a `ViewPager` with out using tabs?

Comment: means one fragment load at a time which is visible .. right.?

Comment: one fragment in a ViewPager without using tabs? means what? can you explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ViewPager is used to navigate between Fragments by only swiping them.

If you want to use only one fragment then it will be meaningless to use `ViewPager`.

Instead you can direct add fragment to the activity using `<fragment>` or `<FrameLayout>`.

Ask me for more query.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it kind of works. But what i am trying to do is where the appbar doesn't move with everything else when i scroll, I'm having so much trouble in trying to do it. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056601/why-does-my-layout-auto-scroll-without-a-scroll-view?noredirect=1#comment83089211_48056601) to the stackoverflow question i asked

Comment: You can use ScrollView surrounded to other view which you want to be scrolled. So Toolbar will be staeady at top if you have make it fixed at top using **android:alignParentTop=true or android:layout_gravity="top"** .

Comment: And If you are using activity toolbar that is default toolbar then you don't need to handle scroll at all.

Comment: Ugh. I appreciate the help but i still cant get it to work. Is it probably because my style has been set to NoActionBar?

Comment: With NoActionBar this will happen for sure, unless you handle it as I said above. Thanks.